# npm run dev install errors on VM with laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, npm, vagrant, scotchbox

I am trying to start using npm and vue for my front end development but having such a hard time starting.  I am using scotchbox pro which is just a Vagrant box for development.  I am running this VM on windows 10 and have a fresh install of laravel 5.4.

The default package.json is there (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/package.json) and I have been trying to run npm install on the with no success for the last few days.

I am not sure where I should be looking for support on this issue since it could be laravel, npm, or my VM.  It is so difficult for me to find a solid resource on how to get up and running!

Here is the npm run dev output that I get:

```
 @ dev /var/www
 npm run development


 @ development /var/www
 cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress -hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

sh: 1: cross-env: not found

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-75-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/bin/npm" "run" "development"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-75-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'npm run development'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run development
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but I recently experienced a very similar (though not identical) error, I deleted my node_modules folder and re-ran `npm install` and it fixed the issue.

Comment: thanks dude.. I tried that.  I have been trying everything and have had zero luck.. I feel like this is some sort of hazing process and so tempted to just forget npm all together. It is such a hassel to get up and running with no cohesive or standardized method to getting started.

Comment: try `npm install --no-bin-links`, if you have errors in the first run just retry the same command.

Comment: i tried doing that command already but still get errors each time i run it

Comment: try updating npm `sudo npm install -g npm` and then remove the node_modules directory and the package-lock.json . then do  `npm install --no-bin-links` and let me know if u get a different error this time.

Answer (score 0):

I found that changing my Vagrant file configuration fixed this issue as it was a folder permission issue.

config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"] }